# Sorting a Hashmap's values with sorted Set

Tags: java, hashmap, sortedset

I have a hashmap with values that both contain and do not contain asterisks (* ). I want to sort my values so that all values with an (* ) come last. I tried using this line of code:

```
    SortedSet<String> orderedValues = new TreeSet<String>(myHashMap.values());
```

but it orders it alphabetically then withing that places all values with an (*) first. is there anyway to reverse that???

Comment: And how do you want 2 values containing `*` to be sorted like?

Comment: @RohitJain i guess they would be in the order of what they were in the original list.

Comment: Can't you write a `Comparator` and pass it to the `TreeSet` ?

Comment: anything containing so, it should be: values without *, then values with one * then values with two *. There will be no values in the list containing more then 2

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you have to write your own `java.util.Comparator` to do customized sorting.  Default String sorting is alphabetical.

EDITED to meet new requirements to group sorting by no asterisks, then all with 1 then all with 2 etc

If you want to group sorting by no asterisks, then all with 1 then all with 2 etc and then inside each grouping, sort alphabetically, then you probably want something like this:

```
public class AsterisksLast implements Comparator<String>{

@Override
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {


    int numAsterisksInO1 = numberOfAsterisksIn(o1);
    int numAsterisksInO2 = numberOfAsterisksIn(o2);

    if(numAsterisksInO1 == numAsterisksInO2){
        //both contain same number of asterisks
        //(which may be 0)
        //sort 
        //alphabetically
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
    //different number of asterisks sort by fewest
    return Integer.compare(numAsterisksInO1, numAsterisksInO2);

}

private int numberOfAsterisksIn(String s){
    char[] chars =s.toCharArray();
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<chars.length; i++){
        if(chars[i] == '*'){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

}

then you need to give it to your TreeSet

```
SortedSet<String> orderedValues = new TreeSet<String>(new AsterisksLast());
orderedValues.addAll(myHashMap.values());
```

Comment: the asterisks can be either the first, the last, the first and the last or one in the middle

Comment: Bug: if none contain asterisks, no sorting is performed. I think you meant `o1ContainsAsterisk == o2ContainsAsterisk`

Comment: @Missmuffut - Zom-B is right—the sorting here is broken. You can make the change he suggested, or use the solution I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should just define a custom Comparator for Strings and pass that in as the Comparator when you build the TreeSet. Here's a similar StackOverflow question with a detailed answer:

[TreeSet Custom Comparator Algo .. String Comparision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092777/treeset-custom-comparator-algo-string-comparision)

You haven't specified exactly what you're doing with the asterisk, but below is an example that sorts based on if the string *contains* an asterisk. Note that I use a `List<String>` here instead of a `HashMap`. The fact that you're getting the values from a `HashMap` isn't actually important—you'd do the same thing for any Java `Collection`.

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","a*","b*");
Comparator<String> starCompare = new Comparator<String>() {
  @Override public int compare(String a, String b) {
    int aStar = a.contains("*") ? 1 : 0;
    int bStar = b.contains("*") ? 1 : 0;
    return (aStar != bStar)
      ? Integer.compare(aStar, bStar)
      : a.compareTo(b);
  }
};
// Without comparator
SortedSet<String> set1 = new TreeSet<String>(strs);
System.out.println(set1); // => [a, a*, b, b*, c]
// With comparator
SortedSet<String> set2 = new TreeSet<String>(starCompare);
set2.addAll(strs);
System.out.println(set2); // => [a, b, c, a*, b*]
```

Notice how for the output of `set2`, which uses the custom `Comparator`, the entries including an `*` are last in the sorted set.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse your `Treeset`

```
 TreeSet<String> treeSetObj = new TreeSet<String>( Collections.reverseOrder() ) ;
```

Comment: Doesn't solve original question. 1. asterisk can occur anywhere, 2. there are characters with values less than '*', like ' '  or '!'.